# Understanding Domains

Tags: probability-distributions, density-function

Working on a problem involving a distribution for $f(x,y) = \frac{c}{(x^2+y^2)^2}$ for $x^2+y^2\geq 1$. I thought to make this a well-defined probability distribution to convert to polar, and got $c=\frac{3}{2}$. However, I have been trying to visualize this function with regard to the marginal distributions of $X$ and $Y,$ and have become really confused. When I start to integrate, say for the marginal of $X,$ I expect my domain to be $x^2 \geq \sqrt{y^2-1}$. However, this gives a bizarre result as then the domain of Y is limited to $[-1,1]$. Is this correct? Any help on getting to the marginal distributions would be appreciated.

Comment: consider both signs of the root. Lets say for the marginal of $X$, we have $x \geq \sqrt{y^2 - 1}$ and $x \leq -(y^2-1)$. So we have two separate integrals to do.

Comment: If $-1 \lt y < 1$ then $x$ can take values above $\sqrt{1-y^2}$ and below $-\sqrt{1-y^2}$ while if $y \le -1$ or $y \ge 1$ then $x$ can take any value.  So the marginal support of $X$ is the whole of $\mathbb R$